# MySQL find difference in rows with duplicate column values

Tags: mysql, group-by, duplicates

Suppose I have a table `TAPS`

```
id sequence card_tap time
1    1         61      1
1    1         62      10 
1    2          2      20
1    2          2      20
2    11        12       5
2    11        12       5
2    12        62       10
2    12        61       20
```

I want to find the rows where `id` and `sequence` are the same while the`card_tap` and `time` is not.

It should return

```
id sequence card_tap time
1    1         61      1
1    1         62      10 
2    12        62       10
2    12        61       20
```

Comment: You have a field called `id` but this isn't a unique identifier? Is this a relational table?

Comment: id and sequence are the same so ID = SEQUENCE ?? and expected output id =2 seq = 12 ?? problem somewhere

Comment: @leo `ID = ID` and `sequence = sequence`

Comment: My bet is this problem arises from a non-normalized dataset. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Note that in the absence of a PRIMARY KEY, you don't really have a table, and, further, you will likely encounter some serious difficulties when trying to build queries against this data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assume there is only two rows for each `{id,sequence}`

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM taps t1
JOIN taps t2
  ON t1.id = t2.id
 AND t1.sequence = t2.sequence
WHERE  t1.time <> t2.time
   OR  t1.card_tap  <> t2.card_tap
```

If you have more than two rows you will get duplicate rows so maybe need add `DISTINCT`

Comment: @strawberry why you think need distinct?

Comment: Well, it's either that or t1.time > t2.time

Comment: @Strawberry I have `WHERE  t1.time <> t2.time`

Comment: @Strawberry row {1,1,61,1} only match with itself and with {1,1,62,10} with itself the values are the same and isnt selected, so only one match is returned. So I dont think `DISTINCT` is need it. But you can show me a sample where got duplicate rows.

Comment: @Strawberry Yes, Im feeling ok, just a little hungry ;). Your example add another row not in OP question. But don't worry I already include that  assumption on the answer just in case and add the distinct as additional fix in case that is a possibility

Comment: I think the more serious point is the absence of a PRIMARY KEY, which makes the whole thing unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: why would you use `<>` instead of `!=`?

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ I dont know, MySql Isnt my day to day db, just solve it as I  usually write my query. Is it wrong? I believe both operator do the same

Comment: I would think that `<>` would be more taxing, since it would look for less than, then greater than for every record `< or >`. However the documentation, expectedly, for MySQL 5.7 shows they return the same results. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal

Answer (score 0):

Simply with this ?

```
Select * from tabs where id = sequence and card_tap != time
```

Comment: if you see OP expected ouput `2 <> 12`

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question

Comment: oh ok.. however this is very bad explanation : "id and sequence are the same" i interpret id = sequence...

Answer (score 0):

The data seems to not be normalized. Anyway, based on your tagging, I'm guessing you're looking for something to return all results like:

```
select distinct * from taps;
```

or

```
select * from taps group by card_tap,time;
```

You need to add a unique `ID` with an `Index` to better deal with the data.

Comment: This return all the rows. But I guess you can add `HAVING AVG()  <> MAX()`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Where are you coming up with `avg()` and `max()` values? They're not looking for limits, simply duplicate records.

Comment: Check OP desire output. You need to return rows where id=id, seq=seq but time or tap are different. Your solution return all rows. But if you group you can tell if they have different values checking if avg() <> max()